# Android toast message (identify the correct answer using radio button)

Tags: java, android, toast

I'm developing a quiz. I got an error while showing my toast message. The error is, if the user taps the correct answer, toast says it is the wrong answer even if I tap the correct choice. Help is really appreciated! Here is the code:

```
public class Question2 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


TextView question, items = null;
RadioButton answer1 = null;
RadioButton answer2 = null;
RadioButton answer3 = null;
RadioGroup answers = null;
int selectedAnswer = -1;
int quesIndex = 0;
int numEvents = 0;
int selected[] = null;
int correctAns[] = null;
boolean review = false;
Button next = null;
int score = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.startquiz);

    try {
        score = getIntent().getIntExtra("score",0);
        items = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayitems);
        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayquestion);
        answer1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option1);
        answer2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option2);
        answer3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option3);
        answers = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.QueGroup1);


        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selected);
        next.setOnClickListener(nextListener);

        selected = new int[Question1.getQuesList().length()];
        java.util.Arrays.fill(selected, -1);
        correctAns = new int[Question1.getQuesList().length()];
        java.util.Arrays.fill(correctAns, -1);

        this.showQuestion(0, review);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
    }

}

private void showQuestion(int qIndex, boolean review) {
    try {
        JSONObject aQues = Question1.getQuesList().getJSONObject(
                qIndex);
        String quesValue = aQues.getString("Question");
        if (correctAns[qIndex] == -1) {
            String correctAnsStr = aQues.getString("CorrectAnswer");
            correctAns[qIndex] = Integer.parseInt(correctAnsStr);
        }

        question.setText(quesValue.toCharArray(), 0, quesValue.length());
        answers.check(-1);
        answer1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        answer2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        answer3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        JSONArray ansList = aQues.getJSONArray("Answers");
        String aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(0).getString("Answer");
        answer1.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(1).getString("Answer");
        answer2.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(2).getString("Answer");
        answer3.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        Log.d("", selected[qIndex] + "");
        if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
            answers.check(R.id.option1);
        if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
            answers.check(R.id.option2);
        if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
            answers.check(R.id.option3);

        setText();
        if (quesIndex == (Question1.getQuesList().length() - 1))
            next.setEnabled(false);

        if (quesIndex < (Question1.getQuesList().length() - 1))
            next.setEnabled(true);

        if (review) {
            Log.d("review", selected[qIndex] + "" + correctAns[qIndex]);
            ;
            if (selected[qIndex] != correctAns[qIndex]) {
                if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
                    answer1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
                    answer2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
                    answer3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 0)
                answer1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 1)
                answer2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 2)
                answer3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
}


private void setAnswer() {
    if (answer1.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 0;
    if (answer2.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 1;
    if (answer3.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 2;



    Log.d("", Arrays.toString(selected));
    Log.d("", Arrays.toString(correctAns));

}

private OnClickListener nextListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        for(int i=0; i<correctAns.length; i++){
            if ((correctAns[i] != -1) && (correctAns[i] == selected[i]))
                    {

                        score++;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your answer is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your answer is wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
        }


        quesIndex++;
        try {
            if (quesIndex >= Question1.getQuesList().length())
                quesIndex = Question1.getQuesList().length() - 1;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        showQuestion(quesIndex, review);

    }
};
private void setText() throws JSONException {
    this.setTitle("Question " + (quesIndex + 1) + "  out of  "
            + Question1.getQuesList().length());
    items.setGravity(250);
}

public void reload() {
    setAnswer();



Intent intent = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();

overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: debug your code with the break point at the if condition and check the values of correctAns[i] and that of selected[i] is it fulfilling the required condition i think there is an issue with the conditioning or with the values of both these check these 1st

Comment: What are the declarations of `correctAns` and `selected`? If they are both `String[]`, then you need to use `equals()` for comparison, not `==`.

Comment: can u post, how u have initialized and put value in `correctAns` and `selected`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can change your condition. Are users be able to select multiple answers?
And try that thin with condition like

```
 for(int i=0; i<correctAns.length; i++){
     if ((correctAns[i].euqalsIgnoreCase(selected[i]))){
         score++;
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your answer is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your answer is wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 }
```

Try this and let me know that it works or not.

Comment: it dont work..the toast message is still showing after i click the next button.it should be when i click the answer (radiobutton), then next button ; the toast will shown up the if i get iinto next question the toast will no longer showing up unless i tap again the next button

Comment: Are the values comes in `selected[]` Have you checked that. I meant that `selected[i]` is getting values from the checkbox.?

Answer (score 0):

Your **If()** condition should be like this:-

```
if ((correctAns[i] != -1) && (correctAns[i].equalsIgnoreCase(selected[i]))) {
    score++;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your answer is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your answer is wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: you r assuming that `correctAns` is a `String[]`, but u have written `correctAns[i] == -1`. please update your answer @amit singh